# How to configure office365 as IDP for SSO using simplesamlphp in php

Tags: php, office365, adfs, simplesamlphp

We are using **simplesamlphp** for SSO to connect with required IDP (Identity Provider) from our SP (Service Provider) and authenticate the users.

And as of now, we did the SSO integration with Google and ADFS services as IDP using simplesamlphp. Now we got a new requirement to do the SSO integration using Office 365 as IDP. Is it possible to do so? 
If yes please give me guidelines on how to do the same.

Excuse me if I am wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://tozny.com/blog/simplesamlphp-office365/ ~ never tried it so I don't know and you may have already seen this

Comment: @RamRaider above link about using simplesamlphp as IDP but in my case I want to use Office 365 as IDP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O365 sits on top of Azure AD so the question is really federating simpleSAMLphp with Azure AD.

AAD allows custom SAML connections via [unlisted applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-custom-apps).

Comment: Thanks above link helped me to understand my requirement.